# JOptionPane List Actions

Tags: java, joptionpane

I want change the icon property of an open `JOptionPane` upon clicking a list item. (They will correspond with each other)

Is there an equivalent to `ActionListener` for this? I know how to code for the buttons, unfortunately these actions are not easy?

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
    "SELECT A PRIMARY WEAPON FROM THE LIST", 
    "ARMOURY", 
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
    get.getIcon("shield_and_swords.png"), 
    character.weaponList(), 
    "Absolix Polearm")
```

Comment: I'm a little lost (I didn't know you could add listings in JOptionPane, and I think you can).  Could you be a bit clearer in your intent?  Perhaps adding code would help, too.

Comment: You add listings to OptionPanes by initiating them with array Objects for arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The [`JOptionPane.showInputDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) documentation states:

> It is up to the UI to decide how best to represent the selectionValues, but usually a JComboBox, JList, or JTextField will be used.

This means the actual GUI element used is implementation-defined and so there couldn't really be a general way to access it, or a consistent action interface to it (it might not even be a clickable list box, for example). Basically, you call `showInputDialog()` and you get a result back, but beyond that it's a black box and the actual GUI could be anything -- no guarantees are made.

Perhaps you could come up with some really dirty object tree hacks to find the GUI element in most cases, but... consider perhaps creating your own custom dialog with a predictable GUI that you can control instead.